# how to copy parent attributes in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created an element and I want it to take attributes (especially the first "parent" class). Here's the code:

JQUERY:

```
$('.secondCategory>ul').prepend('<li class="afterclick"></li>');
```

HTML (how does it look like):

```
<li class="addGradient secondCategory">Lorem ipsum
    <ul class="sub-menu"><li class="afterclick">Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li id="itemsub1><a href="#">Lorem 1</a></li>
        <li id="itemsub2"><a href="#">Lorem 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want the `li` "afterclick" I created to always read the first class (or all classes) of the first `li` element (`<li class = "addGradient secondCategory">`).

Answer (score 1):

If you always know the parent up-front (as you're doing `$('.secondCategory>ul')`) then you can get the class from that element using DOM methods:

```
var parentClass = $('.secondCategory')[0].className
```

then add it when you generate your html:

```js
var parentClass = $('.secondCategory')[0].className

var html = '<li class="' + parentClass + ' afterclick">new element</li>'
$('.secondCategory>ul').prepend(html);
```

```css
li { color: blue; }
li.addGradient { color: red; }
.afterclick { font-style:italic }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="addGradient secondCategory">Lorem ipsum
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="itemsub1"><a href="#">Lorem 1</a></li>
        <li id="itemsub2"><a href="#">Lorem 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

---

If you specifically want it from the "parent", assuming you don't know what the parent will be, then you can keep a reference to the newly appended element and get the parent afterwards, eg:

```js
var html = '<li class="afterclick">new element</li>'

var newElement = $(html).prependTo($('.secondCategory>ul'))

console.log(newElement.parent().parent()[0].className)
newElement.addClass(newElement.parent().parent()[0].className)
```

```css
li { color: blue; }
li.addGradient { color: red; }
.afterclick { font-style:italic }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="addGradient secondCategory">Lorem ipsum
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="itemsub1"><a href="#">Lorem 1</a></li>
        <li id="itemsub2"><a href="#">Lorem 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

In this case I've used `.parent().parent()` as you wanted the classes from the "closest" `li`.